# Marshmallow List of objects with any schema

Tags: python, openapi, aiohttp, marshmallow

I'm using [ApiSpec](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/apispec) in an aiohttp service for building the docs. Now I need to create a JSON method that takes a list of objects in a free form, with no fields restrictions. So, is it possible to specify a schema with a list of objects with any fields / no validation? I mean something like this:

```py
class UploadInfoRequestSchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    objects = marshmallow.fields.List(marshmallow.fields.Nested(*AnySchema*))
```

<sub>Also, I use [aiohttp-apispec](https://github.com/maximdanilchenko/aiohttp-apispec) package which unfortunately supports OpenAPI v2.0 only, so I hope there is solution for this version.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your usecase, you could use Raw or Dict:

```
class UploadInfoRequestSchema(marshmallow.Schema):
    objects = marshmallow.fields.List(marshmallow.fields.Raw())
    objects2 = marshmallow.fields.List(marshmallow.fields.Dict())
```